# Confusion with the order of logical operators in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongo DB and while doing some practising, I came across a weird problem. The schema being:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8eccc1caa187d17ca6ed29"),
    "city" : "CLEVELAND",
    "zip" : "35049",
    "loc" : {
        "y" : 33.992106,
        "x" : 86.559355
    },
    "pop" : 2369,
    "state" : "AL"
} ...
```

I want to find the number of cities, that have a population of more than 5000 but less than 1000000.
Both these queries, this:

`db.zips.find({"$nor":[{"pop":{"$lt":5000}},{"pop":{"$gt":"1000000"}}]}).count()`

and this:

`db.zips.find({"$nor":[{"pop":{"$gt":1000000}},{"pop":{"$lt":"5000"}}]}).count()`

give different results.

The first one gives 11193 and the second one gives 29470. Since I am from MySql background, both the queries are making no difference to me. According to me, both are the same and should return the number of zip codes with a population of less than 1000000 and more than 5000. Please help me understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order of array elements used with `$nor` should not matter AFAIK.  Are you certain that what you are seeing is reproducible?

Comment: yes. I am certain. This data can be tested on dummy data for atlas. data set: sample_training

Comment: your first query quoted "100000" and your second query quoted "5000", they are not the same. Numeric comparison should not be quoted `""`.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial. Bang on now its correct. Please answer this, ill mark it as correct. This will help others in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$gte and $lte should be used to compare same data type.

your first query quoted "100000" and your second query quoted "5000", the two queries ended up as not the same, since you are comparing Numeric data type in one, and string in another.